# .NET Core API seems to deadlock

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have a .NET Core API running in production which can run stable for days or even weeks and then suddenly freezes. Such a freeze can even happen multiple times a day, completely random. What happens: the code seems to be frozen and doesn't accept any new requests. No new requests are logged, the thread count rises sky-high and the memory rises steadily until it's maxed out.

I created a memory dump to analyze. It tells me that most threads are waiting for a lock to be released at a specific function, looking like a deadlock. I analysed this function and cannot see why this would cause issues. Can someone help me out? Obviously I suspect AsParallel() to be thread unsafe, but the internet says no, it is thread safe.

```
public async Task<bool> TryStorePropertiesAsync(string sessionId, Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs, int ttl = 1500)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(keyValuePairs.AsParallel().Select(async item => 
        {
            var doc = await _cosmosDbRepository.GetItemByKeyAsync(GetId(sessionId, item.Key), sessionId) ?? new Document();

            doc.SetPropertyValue("_partitionKey", sessionId);
            doc.SetPropertyValue("key", GetId(sessionId, item.Key));
            doc.SetPropertyValue("name", item.Key.ToLowerInvariant());
            doc.SetPropertyValue("value", item.Value);
            doc.TimeToLive = ttl;
            await _cosmosDbRepository.UpsertDocumentAsync(doc, "_partitionKey");
        }));
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        ApplicationInsightsLogger.TrackException(ex, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "sessionID", sessionId },
            { "action", "TryStoreItems" }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which lock are your threads waiting for, exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't speed up bad queries by parallel execution. You can make them infinitely slower though. If you execute eg 100 single-row SELECTs instead of a single SELECT that retrieves all rows at once, you'll get 100x slower performance. If you try to do that in parallel, you may finish faster or a *lot* slower as your 100 individual connections conflict with each other and possibly UPDATE operations

Comment: Why using also the `AsParallel()`?

Comment: Honestly, it's not my code. So I don't know why they use Parallel.ForEach, but I can think of a reason of course. I'd prefer to just loop through them, add the tasks to a list and await the list at the end. I can and will do that, but I want to understand what is causing the API to stop responding

Comment: `AsParallel()` is meant for *data* parallelism - processing a lot of in-memory data using all cores. That's not the  case here, there's no data. Just IO operations. It doesn't do anything useful either, the real async operations are performed by `GetItemByKeyAsync` and `UpsertDocumentAsync`. You could have used just `someValues.Select(async ....)`

Comment: With or `AsParallel()`, what this code does is fire off as many async operations as there are items. For 100 items, it fires off 100 concurrent operations. Without `AsParallel()`, it does so 1 at a time, although that doesn't matter - just starting the IO is instantaneous. With `AsParallel()`, it fires off the same number of operations, 4 or 8 at a time

Comment: Firing off 100 *concurrent* operations is probably hitting one CosmosDB throttling limit or another. You'd get a lot better performance if you limited the number of concurrent operations. You'll have to experiment to find the correct number. You can use an ActionBlock<T> to easily queue requests and execute them with a specific number of worker tasks

Comment: I will add some more memory dump data here when I can access them tonight. CosmosDb itself is no issue I think... it doesn't even get close to the maximum throughput setup in Cosmos, so no 429 errors as well. In fact, 0 requests are made to Cosmos from one moment to the other

Comment: Why is `GetItemByKeyAsync` called? What does `GetId()` do? You may be able to simply make a **single** call to [DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.upsertdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) instead of that Get, modify, upsert cycle. Eg. just call `client.UpsertDocumentAsync(someUrl,new {key,name,value})`. That alone may reduce conflicts by orders of magnitude, especially if that `GetItemByKeyAsync` takes any kind of locks

Comment: Is _cosmosDbRepository and whatever it uses internally thread safe?

Comment: @Peter the dumps won't help. The code is ... problematic. What is `_cosmosDbRepository`, what do those methods do? They look similar to CosmosDB API calls but *aren't* the same. If you used DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync you wouldn't need any of the other calls. You'd avoid conflicts too

Comment: I belive they did it because because they got poor performance because of exceeding available Cosmos-DB RU's. But doing that in paralell just brings you faster to your RU limit, there're some people at stackoverflow who states that's the solution to poor Cosmos-DB performance issues... When you reach that RU limit everything will get slowed down because there comes some throttling. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/request-units

Comment: As a side node. It could be far faster and use far less RU's when you store your data packed to your Cosmos-DB. But that also have a downside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has serious issues. For eg 100 items, it fires off 100 concurrent operations, 4/8 at a time. The code inside the loop seems to read a document from CosmosDB, set all its properties then call a method named similar to [DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.upsertdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) which *doesn't* need pre-loading anything. Without knowing what `_cosmosDbRepository` is and what its methods do, one can only guess. It's possible it creates extra conflicts though by trying to lock stuff while the (probably useless) load/update cycle takes place.

For starters, `AsParallel()` is only meant for data parallelism: partition some data in memory and use as many workers are there are cores to crunch each partition. There's no data here though, just calls to async operations. That's why for 100 items, this code will fire off 100 concurrent tasks.

That could hit any number of CosmosDB throttling limits, even if it doesn't cause concurrency conflicts. It could also lead to *networking* issues, as the same cable is used for all those concurrent connections.

Not taking CosmosDB into account, the correct way to make lots of calls to a remote service is to queue them and execute them with a limited number of workers. This is very easy to do with .NET's [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.1). The code could change to something like this :

```
class Payload
{
    public string SessionKey{get;set;}
    public string Key{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;}
    public int TTL{get;set;}
}

//Allow only 10 concurrent upserts
var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
  {
     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
  };
var upsertBlock=new ActionBlock<Payload>(myPosterAsync,options);

foreach(var payload in payloads)
{
    block.Post(pair);
}
//Tell the block we're done
block.Complete();
//Await for all queued operations to complete
await block.Completion;
```

Where `myPosterAsync` contains the posting code :

```
async Task myPosterAsync(Payload item)
{
    try
    {
        var doc = await _cosmosDbRepository.GetItemByKeyAsync(GetId(item.SessionId, item.Key), 
                                                          item.SessionId) 
                         ?? new Document();

        doc.SetPropertyValue("_partitionKey", item.SessionId);
        doc.SetPropertyValue("key", GetId(sessionId, item.Key));
        doc.SetPropertyValue("name", item.Name);
        doc.SetPropertyValue("value", item.Value);
        doc.TimeToLive = item.TTL;
        await _cosmosDbRepository.UpsertDocumentAsync(doc, "_partitionKey");
    catch (Exception ex)   
    {
        //Handle the error in some way, eg log it
        ApplicationInsightsLogger.TrackException(ex, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "sessionID", item.SessionId },
            { "action", "TryStoreItems" }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: All I did now was just remove the AsParallel() and replaced it with a simple Select. That did the trick, it's now running stable for almost 2 weeks. That would mean that AsParallel() casuses deadlocks and shouldn't be used in async scenario's. I can live with that obviously, but I still don't understand why it causes deadlocks.

Comment: @Peter I've explained that in the question's comments already. It's meant for data parallelism, not asynchronous operations. It doesn't deadlock, it uses *all* available cores to crunch data. This means, it uses the current thread too. WIthout `AsParalle()` your code creates tasks one by one but never waits for them to finish, until `await Task.WhenAll()` awaits all of them. On the other hand, `AsParallel()` creates those same tasks 4 or 8 at a time, again without waiting for them to finish. It's `await Task.WhenAll` that blocks

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. Your previous comments did explain AsParallel vs Select and the performance difference, but your last comment here made me realize what actually went wrong. Thank you very much